# Git disassociate a branch from its parent

Tags: git, gerrit

[image]

I have the MAX-NAN commit which is a derived off of the MAX-12624 commit. I would like to merge ONLY the MAX-NAN commit, but Gerrit says I need to submit it with its parent.

How can I remove all associations between these two branches such that MAX-12624 can be abandoned while the MAX-NAN can be merged independently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute the following steps:

1. Go to the MAX-NAN change
2. Click on ***Rebase*** button
3. Mark the ***Change parent revision*** checkbox
4. Leave the next field empty
5. Click on ***Rebase*** button

The MAX-NAN change will not depend on the MAX-12624 anymore. Now you can submit MAX-NAN change and abandon MAX-12624 one.